# what is wrong with this code ? pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

class stock:

def **init**(self,ticker):
      self.ticker = ticker
      con = lite.connect(".//stocks.db")
      self.data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM daily where ticker = '" + ticker + "' ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 100",con,index_col="datum")
      con.close()

def data(self):
      print self.data

def ticker(self):
      return self.ticker

def datum(self):
      return self.data.index[0]

```
inv = stock("TSLA")
print inv.ticker
print inv.datum
```

gives this output:

TSLA
main.stock instance at 0x03E061C0>>

so printing of ticker string works, but not last datum field

Comment: Where does datum come from? What classes are you inheriting from?

Comment: Can you post the output from `inv.info()` I'm assuming you're thinking that `datum` column exists?

Comment: @EdChum Where is `inv.info()`?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I believe that the OP is using a pandas dataframe for `inv`

Comment: @EdChum modified the comment to check for inheritance, as I believe that inv is an instance of his class.

Comment: is `stock` the name of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your first errors is you did not close your SQLite connection.

in `__init__`:

```
con.close() # instead of only con.close
```

Your other issue is that [`pandas.read_sql()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) returns a [`pandas.Dataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). After looking at the docs, the pandas Dataframe does not have a method `datum`.

I should also point out that you're not calling many functions; you're only simply looking at what they are. You have to call functions using brackets (`inv.ticker()`), with arguments to that function being located within the brackets.